# Get the handle to a process using its image name

Tags: winapi

I need to obtain the Handle to a process using its
Image Name so that I can use it with TerminateProcess
function.
Any help will be appreciated

Farid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot and Process32First/Next to iterate the running processes.  Figuring out which one you'd want to abort if there's more than one instance of the process is of course not really possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Mr Passant
For those who like examples I one written
using the above functions:
#include <windows.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>

int main(){
  HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe32);
do {
string ProcExe = pe32.szExeFile;
//Now, say you want to terminate Notepad:
if (ProcExe == "notepad.exe"){
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pe32.th32ProcessID);
TerminateProcess(hProcess, NULL);
}
} while(Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe32));
}